# Stop execute javascript until onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, wait

I'm looking for a method that stop excute a javascript until a onclick.

This is my script, but i don't know how to wait until a onclick.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var stat = "*";

function setstat(but)  {
    stat = but;
}

function start() {
    alert('start');
    ...
    ...
    /* ??????? wait until stat != '*' ???????? */
    alert(stat);
    ...
    ...
}   
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type='button' style="width: 100px;" value="Start" onclick="start();">
<br><br>
<input type='button' style="width: 100px;" value="Yes" onclick="setstat('yes')"> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type='button' style="width: 100px;"` ``value="No" onclick="setstat('no')">`
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps `setInterval()` is what you're looking for?

Comment: You should think of dividing the `start() function` into two function. `First()`: containing code above the line where you want to wait. `Second()`: containing rest of the code of `start() function`. You can call `Second()` in `onclick` of second and third `input` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You have to "think" in events. It looks like you want to execute the code at some point in the start function, when the stat is set to 'yes' or 'no'.

Every button `onclick` is calling a function, more precisely it actually expects a statement. Why not refactor your code and do that stuff when you press the yes button?

To make my point clear:

```
var stat = '*';

function start() {
  // code

  //until stat != '*';

  // move this code here -->
}

function setstat(but)  {
  stat = but;
  doReallyStart();
}

function doReallyStart() {
  // to here <--
}
```

This would do the same and is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setTimeout and clearTimeout could satisfy your situation.
you could put your js code in setTimeout,onClick event trigger clearTimeout

Comment: You don't know how much time you have to wait, Interval suits better than Timeout in my opinion. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var execute = false;
var timeoutPolling = 1000;
var fn = function() {
  console.log('Hello');
};
var it = setInterval(function() {
  if (execute) {
    fn();
    clearInterval(it);
  }
}, timeoutPolling);
```

This worked in my Chrome Dev Tools, you just have to enable/disable the `execute` flag.